# Hiding element from another module

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I work on angularjs single page application project

I have two modules in my angularjs project `module-'A'` and `module-'B'`.Each of the modules has view templates.
`Module-'B'` template's view has div with `id ="siteDataView"`, I need to hide this div out of `module-'A'` controller function named `hideMenu()` .

I try it this way:

```
(function () {
"use strict";

  angular.module("module-A").controller("module-A-Controller", ["$state", module-A-Controller]);

  function module-A-Controller() {
    var self = this;

    this.hideMenu = function () {
       var elem = document.getElementById("siteDataView");
       elem.hide();
    }
    self.hideMenu();
  }
})();
```

But the problem is that `elem` variable is always null.

Any idea what do I miss?Why I cant access the element with `id=siteDataView`?

Comment: Show us your html

Comment: `document.getElementById("siteDataView")` is not picking the element.. check the id .. as this is simple DOM manipulation .. run `document.getElementById("siteDataView")` on console and check if there its picking the element.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling hideMenu function within the controller, which won't work. Because modules and controller functions are initiated before creating DOM so during this call elem will be null. Better call this method in ng-init directive in DOM.